# Saving the state of checkboxes

Tags: android, checkbox, save

I have problem with my application. I have an application with checkboxes. How can i save them?

My layout is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lstvw_textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/itemCheckBox"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:text="Switzerland" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lstvw_textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
    android:textSize="14dp"
    android:textColor="#545454"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/itemCheckBox"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:text="Bern" />


<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/itemCheckBox"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:gravity="right" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lstvw_textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/itemCheckBox"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:text="Germany" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lstvw_textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="105dp"
    android:textSize="14dp"
    android:textColor="#545454"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/itemCheckBox"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:text="Berlin" />



<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/itemCheckBox"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:gravity="right" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lstvw_textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/itemCheckBox"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:text="Great Britain" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lstvw_textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="175dp"
    android:textSize="14dp"
    android:textColor="#545454"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/itemCheckBox"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:text="London" />



<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/itemCheckBox"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="160dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:gravity="right" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lstvw_textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="220dp"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/itemCheckBox"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:text="France" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lstvw_textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="245dp"
    android:textSize="14dp"
    android:textColor="#545454"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/itemCheckBox"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:text="Paris" />



<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/itemCheckBox"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="230dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:gravity="right" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And my main.class is:

```
package com.example.capitalcities;

import com.example.capitalcities.R;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class MainActivity2 extends Activity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.settings);

    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
        return true;

    }

}
```

Do you now how to do this?

I hope you understand me, and i hope you could help me.

Comment: Do you need to save them in memory or save it to disk (and reload from either)

Comment: Store them to shared preferences and read once settings are opened or whenever you need them

Comment: I need to save them, close application and then I want to open the same settings. Could you help me with the shared preferences? (Could you rewrite the code please?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use SharedPreferences to store your checkboxes as boolean.

Something like :

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferencesManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
checkBoxDummy.setChecked(sharedPreferences.getBoolean("checkBoxDummy", false));
```

To store values, use a listener. Something like :

```
checkBoxDummy.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked) {
        sharedPreferences.putBoolean("checkBoxDummy", isChecked);
    }
});
```

Comment: You have everything you need to do this by yourself, actually. Just copy/past, basically